# Setting a gallery in amp lightbox with Django

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x, amp-html

I have been working on a project with **Django** on the back-end and **amp** on the front-end; although I am having some troubles to link both tags like the `lightbox` one.

I would like to get a list of first images on my product page (I have done it) and by clicking on an image it displays me the other images of that object on a `lightbox` without going to the detail template.

The whole project is updated on GitHub at:
https://github.com/lucasrf27/dealership

That is the `amp` code that I am trying to.  I am trying this one on `test.amp.html` besides put on my category. (product template)

```
<body>
    <h1>lucas</h1>
    <div>
        {% for v in veiculos %}
        <h1>{{v.modelo}}</h1>
        <amp-img lightbox="cars" src="{{ v.first_image.imagem.url }}" width="" height="" layout="fill" alt="{{v.modelo}}">
            <amp-carousel lightbox="cars" width="350" height="350" type="slides">
    <div>
        {% for v in veiculos %}
        <h1>{{v.modelo}}</h1>
        <amp-img lightbox="cars" src="{{ v.first_image.imagem.url }}" width="300" height="400" alt="{{v.modelo}}">
            <amp-carousel lightbox="cars" width="350" height="350" type="slides">
                {% for p in veiculos.images.all %}
                <amp-img lightbox="cars" src="{{p.imagem.url}}" width="" height="" layout="fill" alt="{{v.modelo}}"></amp-img>
                {% endfor %}
            </amp-carousel>
        </amp-img>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
            </amp-carousel>
        </amp-img>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <!-- These will belong to a different lightbox gallery -->
    <div>
        <amp-img lightbox="another" src="image3.jpg" width="400" height="300" layout="responsive"></amp-img>
        <amp-img lightbox="another" src="image4.jpg" width="400" height="300" layout="responsive"></amp-img>
    </div>
```

When I open the images from the `lightbox` on a new URL,

I get this one:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/veicles/image3.jpg (404)

However the image is in this one:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/veiculos_imagens/bugat-logo-whatsapp-fundo-transparente3.png

Is there some sort of `media_prefix` or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've got the results in a silly way. besides setting on my views or my template a set up a object in function like i did in first_image but for the second and the other 2
it got like:

```
template
<body>
    <h1>lucas</h1>
    {% for v in veiculos %}
    <amp-carousel lightbox width="1600" height="900" layout="responsive" type="slides">
        <amp-img src="{{v.first_image.imagem.url}}" width="200" height="100"></amp-img>
        <amp-img src="{{v.second_image.imagem.url}}" width="200" height="100"></amp-img>
    </amp-carousel>
    {% endfor %}
```

models:

```
    def first_image(self):
        return self.images.first()  

    def second_image(self):
        return self.images.all()[1]
```

if anyone in the future is not understanding the project try to access:
https://github.com/lucasrf27/dealership